# Switching between Map themes in QGIS - lettering settings stay in both themes

Tags: qgis, theme, maptheme

I'm using map themes in QGIS in order to make the preview map in the print composer look different from the main map. But when I change the lettering for the preview-map theme, it is also changed for the main map. I can't make QGIS to memorize that for the one layer that I want lettering on that very layer for the other theme not. What am I doing wrong?